# Dynamically load the menu items created from the links.task.yml file

Tags: 8, navigation

I need to programmatically load the links that are generated from  my_module.links.task.yml on another page.

My exact use case is that I have a set of links that are shown when viewing my node page. The links will be shown and hidden based on the current user's access and the access control is handled through the options in the my_module.routing.yml file.

I need to create a separate page that displays node data in a table and I need to show these links in a drop-down option (similar to how the edit button functions when viewing content as an admin).

Is there a way to dynamically get the links so I can then display them in that drop-down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load **all** module defined menu links (i.e. links defined in **.menu.links.yml* with the [MenuLinkManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21MenuLinkManager.php/class/MenuLinkManager/8.2.x) service's [`getDefinitions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21MenuLinkManager.php/function/MenuLinkManager%3A%3AgetDefinitions/8.2.x) method and then parse the list for only links defined by your module.

```
$all_module_link_definitions = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link')
  ->getDefinitions();

// Next parse the list for only links defined by my_module.
$my_module_link_definitions = [];
foreach ($all_module_link_definitions as $plugin_id => $plugin_definition) {
  if ($plugin_definition['provider'] === 'MY_MODULE') {
    $my_module_link_definitions[$plugin_id] => $plugin_definition;
  }
}
```

Similarly, you can load **all** module defined local tasks with the [LocalTaskManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21LocalTaskManager.php/class/LocalTaskManager/8.2.x) service's [`getDefintions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21LocalTaskManager.php/function/LocalTaskManager%3A%3AgetDefinitions/8.2.x) method and then parse the list for only tasks defined by your module.

```
$all_module_task_definitions = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.local_task')
  ->getDefinitions();

// Next parse the list for only tasks defined by my_module.
$my_module_task_definitions = [];
foreach ($all_module_task_definitions as $plugin_id => $plugin_definition) {
  if ($plugin_definition['provider'] === 'MY_MODULE') {
    $my_module_task_definitions[$plugin_id] => $plugin_definition;
  }
}
```